# How to dispatch actions on location change with react router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I am using `react-router-4.0.0-beta.4` with redux, I am trying to figure out the best way to dispatch actions on route change. I see that a few versions ago there was an API/event hook for this [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/7f6706dab4827afc1c26a58418f8ef8c8ab40125/website/examples/Redux.js#L56). But I see that it is now gone. Trying to do the modern equivalent of what `redux-router` did.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the best way to dispatch an action is to do so at component's `componentWillMount()`, `componentDidMount()` or `componentWillUnmount()` methods.

***IGNORE WHATS BELOW***

There is `onEnter` prop. Like here [comet-frontend](https://github.com/patrykcieszkowski/comet-frontend/blob/master/client/index.js#L81)

> **onEnter**(nextState, replace, callback?)
>
> Called when a route is about to be entered. It provides the next
>   router state and a function to redirect to another path. this will be
>   the route instance that triggered the hook.
>   https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#onenternextstate-replace-callback

BUT, there still is onChange prop, doing exactly what you described. Maybe tell us what exactly is your issue. Because seems like you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Ok, I thought that might be it, I saw a few discussions on github alluding to this. I tried using the `onChange` prop verbatim and it didnt seem to work. It would be nice if `BrowserRouter` had a "global" hook for location changes.

Comment: Yeah. I don't actually understand why they decided to get rid of those props. It kept the code clean.

Answer (score 0):

So you have to wrap your main application component in a `withRouter` and react based on props changing in the props that `withRouter` passes down, namely the `props.location.pathname` for example.

You can see a discussion of how it may work here https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4603